# Open an existing file from Vim

Tags: command-line, vim

I would like to open a file that already exists while already in Vim.

What is the command to do this?

Comment: You should find yourself a nice cheat sheet such as this one https://www.reddit.com/r/vim/comments/32r85c/this_is_my_favorite_vim_cheat_sheet_does_anyone/

Answer (score 82, accepted):

`vim [your file]`

If this isn't working for you, make sure you have it installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

If you're already IN vim do

```
:edit [your file]
```

Additionally, to move back to the previous file after you finish editing the new file you can use

```
:e#
```

This will return you to the previous file

Comment: It says "Invalid search pattern or delimiter". And I have installed vim with this command.

Comment: When does it say that? When you try to open it from the command line? Or when you're already in vim?

Comment: When I am in vim.

Comment: What is the exact command you're typing?

Comment: vim [full path]

Comment: If you're in vim you have to do `:edit [full path]`

Comment: // , @Musher, wouldst consider making the part of this answer that addresses the *while already IN Vim* part more prominent?

Comment: Additionally, use vim buffers to switch between files :ls :b[n], etc.

Comment: And `:e#2` to jump to the second file, etc.

Answer (score 30):

You can also use tabs and split views:

```
:tabe /path/to/file
```

Effect:
[image]

```
:vs /path/to/file
```

(or `:sp` for a horizontal split)
Effect:
[image]

Use `:tabn`, `:tabp` to navigate between tabs, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> with the arrow keys to navigate between splits.

Comment: Isn't it `:sp` to split horizontally?

Comment: @kuzyn indeed. My bad.