# How to open two different files using the vi editor?

Tags: command-line, vi

I have two files in different locations and I want to open these two files with the same `vi` command. How can I do it?

- File 1 location: `/home/rs/rest.pl`
- File 2 location: `/home/dev/grd.pl`

Comment: For what its worth, there is a beta site just for Vi/Vim: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 38, accepted):

[As noted by Zanna](https://askubuntu.com/a/922222/158442), use multiple arguments to Vi. However, Vi(m) by default doesn't show the files at once. They're loaded into buffers and and you can switch to the next (or previous) buffers using [`:bn`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#%3Abn) and `:bp`. If you want to see the files at the same time, use windows (splits):

```
vim /some/file1 /some/file2 -o # horizontal split
vim /some/file1 /some/file2 -O # vertical split
```

Or tabs:

```
vim /some/file1 /some/file2 -p # Open up to 10 files in tabs
```

However, buffers are what Vim actually uses for manipulating files, tabs and windows are merely ways to visually arrange them. Do get used to using buffers directly, instead of via multiple windows or tabs.

(These options also apply to Ubuntu's `vi`, which is `vim.tiny` by default. `vim-tiny` is built with [`+windows`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%2Bwindows), so tabs and windows are enabled.)

See also:

- [Vi & Vim: What is a more efficient way to use buffers?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/9156/205)
- [Open an existing file from Vim](https://askubuntu.com/q/537935/158442)
- SO: [Why do Vim experts prefer buffers over tabs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/2072269) and [Using Vim's tabs like buffers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/2072269)
- [Vim help: Editing with multiple windows and buffers](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/windows.txt.html#windows-intro)

Answer (score 12):

You can call call vi (or vim) with multiple arguments

```
vi /home/rs/rest.pl /home/dev/grd.pl
```

You are in the first file, but both are open. You can switch between them using `:n` (next file) and `:N` (last file) (press <kbd>esc</kbd> to get out of insert mode if necessary).

<sub>I notice those files are in different users' home directories, so you may not have permission as a normal user. To edit files that your user does not have sufficient permissions to edit, you will need `sudo`. You can run the command with `sudo` initially, or use a trick when saving the file `:w !sudo tee %`</sub>

Comment: +1 for the `:w !sudo tee %` trick!

Answer (score 1):

If you like to view the two files tiled horizontally, use

```
vi -o /home/rs/rest.pl /home/dev/grd.pl
```

[image]